# Perl: how to convert unicode symbols to something that will survive trip into and out of database and render in HTML

Tags: html, perl, unicode, character-encoding

TL;DR I have input that looks like this:

```
इस परीक्षण के लिए है
Something
Zürich
```

This data is then piped through a few programs and is ultimately inserted into a mongodb database.
But by the time I query it out and try to display it on a web page it's all garbage.

I've found a lot of questions on how to encode these things but all the answers assume you want everything encoded and do not discuss how to decode it for display.

I only want the "weird" stuff encoded, so for the above I'd like to get some output like this

```
0x1234;0x8737;0x838784; ...
Something
Z0x8387;rich
```

which would store fine in a database, and would survive a vim edit or whatever else, but then when I pull it out I want it to render correctly.

So how do I do that, encode in Perl and decode in Javascript?

PS: I don't know what that string of symbols means, just found it somewhere. Sorry if it's offensive or something. Thanks!

**Edit:**
choroba's answer is a very good start, let's see with an example of what the algorithm produces:

```
input: 株式会社イノ設計
output: 0x230;0x160;0x170;0x229;0x188;0x143;0x228;0x188;0x154;0x231;0x164;0x190;0x227;0x130;0x164;0x227;0x131;0x142;0x232;0x168;0x173;0x232;0x168;0x136;
```

Now how do I render that in Javascript? 0xNN was just an example of what I imagine the answer would be but if there's a better way by all means!

Thanks!

Comment: Perl can handle these characters just OK, as can Javascript and Mongo. Fix the error in the Perl program or in one of the "few programs" and everything will work. Provide more details if you want us to help you identify where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, I'd prefer to just have the text in a more portable format then, that can be copy pasted with the mouse between two terminals etc. Basically I want ascii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that produces something similar to what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub escape {
    my ($in) = @_;
    $in =~ s/([\x{80}-\x{ffff}])/sprintf '0x%d;', ord $1/ger
}

my $in = "Z\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}rich";
my $out = 'Z0x252;rich';

$out eq escape($in) or die escape($in) . "\n$out\n";
```

You seem to want decimal digits after `0x`. That's confusing as `0x` usually means *hexa*decimal. To get hexadecimal codes, change the [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) template to `0x%x;`.

Also note that once someone enters `0x123;` into your data directly, the data will become corrupted.

If you use `&#` instead of `0x` at the beginning of each replaced character, the browser will render the characters correctly: `Z&#252;rich` renders as "Zürich".